# Sublime Text 3 no longer automatically inserts a blank line with indent after hitting return between tag pairs

Tags: sublimetext3

I've discovered an annoying problem after updating ST3 to the latest version, 3114: when autocompleting a tag pair with `tab`, I used to be able to then hit `return` to insert a new blank line between the two tags, and have the cursor sitting waiting on it at the correct indentation. Now it just inserts a line break, as per a standard text-editor.

Could anyone advise how I can get the old behaviour working again?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Keith, thanks for your comment. The console log simply outputs `command: insert {"characters": "\n"}` when I do as you suggest. As far as I'm aware `enter` and `return` are the same thing... I'm hitting the big key at the right side of my keyboard! :)

Comment: Nope, `shift+return` doesn't make a difference. `view.settings().get('auto_indent')` outputs `True`

Comment: hmm, does executing `view.run_command('auto_indent_tag')` do anything, while the cursor is between a tag pair?

Comment: Yes! That produces the behaviour I'm looking for... so how to make this happen on pressing enter..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112883/discussion-between-keith-hall-and-inigo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the default keybinding is either not present or not working for some reason.

It should be possible to fix by creating your own "user" keybinding for it.
To do this, go to the `Preferences` menu -> `Keybindings - User`, and paste in the following:

```
{ "keys": ["enter"], "command": "auto_indent_tag", "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "punctuation.definition.tag.begin", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": ">$", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^</", "match_all": true },
    ]
},
```

Note: If your keybinding file was previously empty, you will need to wrap that whole text in square brackets (`[` and `]`).

Save the file, and you should find that pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> between a tag pair works as expected.